# I need to add a collection value to database . Which is the efficient way to do it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, collections, asp.net-mvc-5

1. Do I need to pass a class objects to the Model method and process it one at a time?

Eg.

```
public async Task<int> SaveCollectionValues(Foo foo)
{
   ....
   //Parameters
   MySqlParameter prmID = new MySqlParameter("pID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
   prmID.Value = foo.ID;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(prmID);

   ....
}


(OR)
```

2. Shall I pass the Collection value to the Model method and use foreach to iterate through the collection

```
public async Task<int> SaveCollectionValues(FooCollection foo)
{
   ....

   //Parameters
   foreach(Foo obj in foo)
   {
   MySqlParameter prmID = new MySqlParameter("pID", MySqlDbType.Int32);
   prmID.Value = foo.ID;
   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(prmID);

   ....
   }
   ....
}
```

I just need to know which of the above mentioned method would be efficient to use?

Answer (score 1):

Efficient is a bit relative here since you didn't specify which database. Bulk insert might change from one to another DB. SQL Server, for instance, uses BCP, while MySQL has a way to disable some internals while sending many insert/update commands.

Apart from that, if you're submitting a single collection at once and that should be handled as a single transaction, than the best option, from both code organization and SQL optimization, is to use both connection sharing and a single transaction object, as follows:

```
public void DoSomething(FooCollection collection)
{
    using(var db = GetMyDatabase())
    {
        db.Open();
        var transaction = db.BeginTransaction();

        foreach(var foo in collection)
        {
           if (!DoSomething(foo, db, transaction))
           { transaction.Rollback(); break; }
        }

    }
}

public bool DoSomething(Foo foo, IDbConnection db, IDbTransaction transaction)
{
    try
    {
        // create your command (use a helper?)
        // set your command connection to db
        // execute your command (don't forget to pass the transaction object)
        // return true if it's ok (eg: ExecuteNonQuery > 0)
        // return false it it's not ok
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
        // this might not work 100% fine for you.
        // I'm not logging nor re-throwing the exception, I'm just getting rid of it.
        // The idea is to return false because it was not ok.
        // You can also return the exception through "out" parameters.
    }
}
```

This way you have a clean code: one method that handles the entire collection and one that handles each value.

Also, although you're submitting each value, you're using a single transaction. Besides of a single commit (better performance), if one fails, the entire collection fails, leaving no garbage behind.

If you don't really need all that transaction stuff, just don't create the transaction and remove it from the second method. Keep a single connection since that will avoid resources overuse and connection overhead.

Also, as a general rule, I like to say: "Never open too many connections at once, specially when you can open a single one. Never forget to close and dispose a connection unless you're using connection poolling and know exactly how that works".